# Processing large text files through Nifi returns null

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm having a pretty weird issue.

I currently have a nifi flow which uses a getfile processor to grab a log file that is dropped in a directory. From there, its passed to a custom processor where the file is processed inside of session.read using the BufferedReader class. I do all of my necessary processing and pass the flow files on. Simple stuff

This works perfectly fine for moderately sized files but when I try to process a large log file (around 2.5GB) I start getting null returned when trying to call readLine() from buffered reader. It seems as if very large files aren't being opened/read by the bufferedreader.

Any advice on areas to troubleshoot to figure out why this behavior is happening for bigger files and not to smaller files?

Comment: NiFi doesn't do anything different based on the size of the flow file content.

Comment: You should consider making a test for your processor using the test framework and analyzing its behavior there.  If you share your code for your custom processor there may be something that could be problematic but it is difficult to diagnose without knowing its functionality and/or libraries used.

Comment: Did you try to split the file before porcessing it?

Comment: @ÓscarAndreu no I didn't. I'm trying to read the file as is

Comment: @crazyCoder I create a response with some trics that works for me, hope it helps.

Comment: Can you monitor your JVM heap use when this large file is loaded! and it might be the case where you need to upgrade your bootstrap JVM values

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the file in smaller pieces, like for example 1000 lines per flowfile, you can do this using the [SplitText](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitText/index.html) component.
I had this problem in the past and was solved using this approach.
Also can happens that the SplitText block NiFi, in this case you can concat several SplitText to split in 100000 lines -> 10000 lines -> 1000 lines, with this trick you can avoid this problem.